# Where are the PRL and profile stored on the filesystem?

Tags: backup, file-system, partitions, profiles, carriers

I'm talking about what can be updated in Settings->More->Cellular networks->Carrier settings. Where are they stored? On what partition and where, if anywhere, on the filesystem?